# How to add two digits to the end of an integer without casting to string?

Tags: c#

I have an integer id generator and I want to add two digits to the end of each id, let's say an id is `20120719`, and add `56` to the id,  then the result is `2012071956`.

I could cast the two integers to string, concatenate the two numbers in string and then cast the result to integer, but this looks inefficiently.

What's the best practice to do this in C#?

Comment: In most languages: `20120719 * 100 + 56`

Comment: will the amount of digits that you want to add be variable? is it known at runtime or compiletime?

Comment: I think two time casting is normal way to do: but also you can make an extension method and do this for you.

Comment: "but this looks inefficiency" how many of those manipulation do you intend to perform? 10-20 ?=! or more  like 10E6 - 20E6 ?

Comment: If it's guaranteed that adding two digits will not cause overflow, the suggestion by @phuzi is the only sane thing to do: (i * 100) + suffix. **IF**. But I think you should pay attention in working with numeric Ids in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the integer type you're using is large enough, simple math will do:

```
var result = 20120719 * 100 + 56;
```

It's a good idea to verify your invariants when doing things like this, so that you can properly handle a case where you get e.g. 156 instead of 56 by accident. A more generic function might work like this:

```
static int AddSuffixToId(int id, int suffix)
{
  if (id < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(id));
  if (suffix < 0 || suffix >= 100) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(suffix));

  // If we get an overflow, we need to know about it; by default, 
  // overflows are silently ignored
  checked
  {
    return id * 100 + suffix;
  }
}
```

Comment: `static int AddSuffixToId...` (we don't want `this`); if you check for `suffix < 0` then it may be reasonable to check for `id < 0`

Comment: `static int AddSuffixToId(int id, int suffix) =>
      suffix >= 0 && suffix < 100
        ? checked(id * 100 + suffix)
        : throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(suffix));`